# Mat-Date with appearance='fill'' is not rendering properly in IE11 and Edge

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using matformfeilds in my angular app with material apperance as "fill". The `mat-datepicker` is not getting rendered properly in IE if I do that. It display correctly in chrome though. If I remove `apperance="fill"` then it shows up fine. But I want the look and feel of fill. Please help.

```
<mat-form-field class="p-form-control" appearance="fill">
                                    <mat-label class="mat-label">Closing Date</mat-label>
                                    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker"
                                            formControlName="ClosingDate">
                                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                                    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
                                    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Probably a bug. Did you check their issues?

Comment: I tried checking I didn't find anything. I think its a bug too. I'm looking for a work around.

Comment: I suggest you create a working Stackblitz to make it easy for others to try to fix it. (Some of us are busy and/or lazy ;)).